# Подскажите, пожалуйста, книги про численные методы или математическим моделям с примерами кода на с++/python

Tags: книги, численные-методы

Потребовалось реализовать математическую модель какого-либо физического явления.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, литературу (желательно с примером кода на Python / C++), если таковая существует, или ссылки на источники, в которых поднимается подобная тема.

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Давайте более конкретно, какого физического явления. Потому что модели бывают очень разными по сложности, начиная с банальной однопрохдной разностной схемы, которуй можно закодить весьма тривиально. И заканчивая методом конечных элементов с автогенерацией сеток и решением на кластере с GPU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Численные методы, Вычислительный практикум, Вабищевич П.Н.